# Finding distinct values with NTH_VALUE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a `pageviews` table that contains the paths of pages visited by customers within each session along with a timestamp. One of the columns is `landing_page`, which is populated for each row in the table (each session's pageviews will all have the same `landing_page`).

I'm trying to create similar columns for `second_page`, `third_page` and `fourth_page`, which will show the paths of the 2nd, 3rd and 4th pages visited in a session. I'm able to do this using NTH_VALUE, but I want to handle a specific case where a customer visits the same page multiple times.

For example, let's say the customer visits pages in the following order -

1. www.dummywebsite.com/
2. www.dummywebsite.com/products
3. www.dummywebsite.com/products
4. www.dummywebsite.com/products/prodA
5. www.dummywebsite.com/cart

With my query (below), I get the `second_page` = "www.dummywebsite.com/products" as well as the `third_page` = "www.dummywebsite.com/products". What I'd like is for `third_page` to be "www.dummywebsite.com/products/prodA" instead.

How can I edit the below query to get the desired result?

```
SELECT pageview_id, session_id, user_id, created_at, landing_page, path,
       NTH_VALUE(path,2 ignore nulls) OVER(win) second_page_path,
       NTH_VALUE(path,3 ignore nulls) OVER(win) third_page_path,
       NTH_VALUE(path,4 ignore nulls) OVER(win) fourth_page_path
   FROM pageviews
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id, session_id ORDER BY created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

Comment: then what will be the 4th page

Comment: 4th page would be www.dummywebsite.com/cart

Comment: @Moon_Watcher . . . I'm confused.  I am expecting `group by session_id` to get one row per session, rather than one row per page view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be easier if you'd put some sample data up but something along these lines should remove the paths that are a duplicate of previous paths

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT pageview_id, session_id, user_id, created_at, landing_page, path,
if(path=lag(path) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id, user_id ORDER BY created_at),FALSE,TRUE) distinctPath
FROM pageviews)

SELECT pageview_id, session_id, user_id, created_at, landing_page, path,
   NTH_VALUE(path,2 ignore nulls) OVER(win) second_page_path,
   NTH_VALUE(path,3 ignore nulls) OVER(win) third_page_path,
   NTH_VALUE(path,4 ignore nulls) OVER(win) fourth_page_path
FROM pageviews
WHERE distinctPath = TRUE
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id, session_id ORDER BY created_at ROWS BETWEEN 
 UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL with minimal changes to your original query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT pageview_id, session_id, user_id, created_at, landing_page, path,
  NTH_VALUE(distinct_path,2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) second_page_path,
  NTH_VALUE(distinct_path,3 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) third_page_path,
  NTH_VALUE(distinct_path,4 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) fourth_page_path
FROM (
  SELECT pageview_id, session_id, user_id, created_at, landing_page, path,
    IF(path = LAG(path) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, session_id ORDER BY created_at), NULL, path) distinct_path 
  FROM `project.dataset.pageviews`
)
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id, session_id ORDER BY created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

Answer (score 0):

below query will change the third_page_path

```
SELECT pageview_id, session_id, user_id, created_at, landing_page, path,
           NTH_VALUE(path,2 ignore nulls) OVER(win) second_page_path,
           NTH_VALUE(path,4 ignore nulls) OVER(win) third_page_path,
           NTH_VALUE(path,4 ignore nulls) OVER(win) fourth_page_path
       FROM pageviews
    WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id, session_id ORDER BY created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

Comment: this only works for the example given. I'm looking for a more general solution where the next distinct page is chosen in the window function.